# Bug in HttpsURLConnection debug values

Tags: java, httpsurlconnection

I'm documenting something I can only qualify as a bug in the debug values of **javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection** instances.

I created a Java EE project in Eclipse, another in Netbeans, and in both cases wrote a simple method which when called will execute the following code:

```
URL url = new URL(sHttpsEndpoint);
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
System.out.println("Value for request method is: " + conn.getRequestMethod());

conn.setDoOutput(true);
System.out.println("Value for doOutput is : " + conn.getDoOutput());
```

My issue arises when I try to inspect the HttpsURLConnection instance I created.

- In Eclipse, I double click *conn* and then right click - Inspect.
- In Netbeans, I hover over *conn* while debugging.

It seems the **data provided when I inspect the class instance is the class' default data, not the real data.**

In both cases, if I log the data using *System.out.println* or *watch* it, the class' actual data is provided.

Please see the screenshots below.

[image]
*Eclipse*

[image] 
*Netbeans*

Based on my research on SO and the web in general, it seems others have in fact found buggy behaviour inside this class. In addition, [the Java bugs database](http://bugs.java.com) has several bugs reported for this class. However, I haven't managed to find this particular issue reported anywhere yet.

How can this be explained? Can someone think of any other explanation for this behaviour?

- Java version: 1.7
- Eclipse version: Luna
- Netbeans version: 8.1
- OS: Windows 10

Comment: IMHO its more case of the debugger itself(lags etc. )  than java bug.

Comment: Well, AFAIK Netbeans and Eclipse use two different debuggers? And I've never had this error with any other class.

Comment: Did You tried to test this case in Intellij IDEA? Maybe its debugger can give proper results.

Comment: No, I didn't - I don't have Intellij. Do you really think it's debugger would be different to Eclipse and Netbeans' ?